# GeoServer / GWC / WMTS Return (400) Bad Request for part of map

Tags: openstreetmap, geoserver

I am trying to setup a Open Street Map (OSM) with PostGIS + GeoServer

The map has been imported to PostGIS.

GeoServer is configured and working fine with "Preview Layer Group".

But when I try to use "Tile Layers" examples some tiles of the map doesn't render.

The html code that calls GeoServer is generated by GeoServer itself.

All Zoom levels are OK with the gridset chosen.

Beginning of WMTS GetCapabilities:

```html
<Capabilities xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wmts/1.0/wmtsGetCapabilities_response.xsd" version="1.0.0">
<ows:ServiceIdentification>
<ows:Title>GeoServer Web Map Tile Service</ows:Title>
<ows:Abstract>A compliant implementation of WMTS service.</ows:Abstract>
<ows:Keywords/>
<ows:ServiceType>OGC WMTS</ows:ServiceType>
<ows:ServiceTypeVersion>1.0.0</ows:ServiceTypeVersion>
<ows:Fees>NONE</ows:Fees>
<ows:AccessConstraints>NONE</ows:AccessConstraints>
</ows:ServiceIdentification>
<ows:ServiceProvider>
<ows:ProviderName>http://geoserver.org</ows:ProviderName>
<ows:ServiceContact>
<ows:IndividualName>Claudius Ptolomaeus</ows:IndividualName>
<ows:PositionName>Chief Geographer</ows:PositionName>
<ows:ContactInfo>
<ows:Address>
<ows:City>Alexandria</ows:City>
<ows:Country>Egypt</ows:Country>
<ows:ElectronicMailAddress>claudius.ptolomaeus@gmail.com</ows:ElectronicMailAddress>
</ows:Address>
</ows:ContactInfo>
</ows:ServiceContact>
</ows:ServiceProvider>
<ows:OperationsMetadata>
<ows:Operation name="GetCapabilities">
<ows:DCP>
<ows:HTTP>
<ows:Get xlink:href="http://xxxxxx/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?">
<ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
<ows:AllowedValues>
<ows:Value>KVP</ows:Value>
</ows:AllowedValues>
</ows:Constraint>
</ows:Get>
</ows:HTTP>
</ows:DCP>
</ows:Operation>
<ows:Operation name="GetTile">
<ows:DCP>
<ows:HTTP>
<ows:Get xlink:href="xxxxxx/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?">
<ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
<ows:AllowedValues>
<ows:Value>KVP</ows:Value>
</ows:AllowedValues>
</ows:Constraint>
</ows:Get>
</ows:HTTP>
</ows:DCP>
</ows:Operation>
<ows:Operation name="GetFeatureInfo">
<ows:DCP>
<ows:HTTP>
<ows:Get xlink:href="http://xxxxxx/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?">
<ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
<ows:AllowedValues>
<ows:Value>KVP</ows:Value>
</ows:AllowedValues>
</ows:Constraint>
</ows:Get>
</ows:HTTP>
</ows:DCP>
</ows:Operation>
</ows:OperationsMetadata>
<Contents>
<Layer>
<ows:Title>Pk50095</ows:Title>
<ows:Abstract>
Pk50095 is a raster file accompanied by a spatial data file.
</ows:Abstract>
<ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
<ows:LowerCorner>12.999446822650462 46.722110379286</ows:LowerCorner>
<ows:UpperCorner>13.308182612644663 46.91359611878293</ows:UpperCorner>
</ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
<ows:Identifier>nurc:Pk50095</ows:Identifier>
<Style isDefault="true">
<ows:Identifier>raster</ows:Identifier>
<LegendURL format="image/png" xlink:href="http://xxxxxx/geoserver/ows?service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&format=image%2Fpng&width=20&height=20&layer=nurc%3APk50095" width="20" height="20"/>
</Style>
<Format>image/png</Format>
<Format>image/jpeg</Format>
<InfoFormat>text/plain</InfoFormat>
<InfoFormat>application/vnd.ogc.gml</InfoFormat>
<InfoFormat>text/xml</InfoFormat>
<InfoFormat>application/vnd.ogc.gml/3.1.1</InfoFormat>
<InfoFormat>text/xml</InfoFormat>
<InfoFormat>text/html</InfoFormat>
<InfoFormat>application/json</InfoFormat>
<TileMatrixSetLink>
<TileMatrixSet>EPSG:4326</TileMatrixSet>
<TileMatrixSetLimits>
<TileMatrixLimits>
<TileMatrix>EPSG:4326:0</TileMatrix>
<MinTileRow>0</MinTileRow>
<MaxTileRow>0</MaxTileRow>
<MinTileCol>1</MinTileCol>
<MaxTileCol>1</MaxTileCol>
</TileMatrixLimits>
<TileMatrixLimits>
<TileMatrix>EPSG:4326:1</TileMatrix>
<MinTileRow>0</MinTileRow>
<MaxTileRow>0</MaxTileRow>
<MinTileCol>2</MinTileCol>
<MaxTileCol>2</MaxTileCol>
</TileMatrixLimits>
<TileMatrixLimits>
<TileMatrix>EPSG:4326:2</TileMatrix>
<MinTileRow>0</MinTileRow>
<MaxTileRow>0</MaxTileRow>
<MinTileCol>4</MinTileCol>
<MaxTileCol>4</MaxTileCol>
</TileMatrixLimits>
<TileMatrixLimits>
<TileMatrix>EPSG:4326:3</TileMatrix>
<MinTileRow>1</MinTileRow>
<MaxTileRow>1</MaxTileRow>
<MinTileCol>8</MinTileCol>
<MaxTileCol>8</MaxTileCol>
</TileMatrixLimits>
<TileMatrixLimits>
<TileMatrix>EPSG:4326:4</TileMatrix>
<MinTileRow>3</MinTileRow>
<MaxTileRow>3</MaxTileRow>
<MinTileCol>17</MinTileCol>
<MaxTileCol>17</MaxTileCol>
</TileMatrixLimits>
<TileMatrixLimits>
<TileMatrix>EPSG:4326:5</TileMatrix>
<MinTileRow>7</MinTileRow>
<MaxTileRow>7</MaxTileRow>
<MinTileCol>34</MinTileCol>
<MaxTileCol>34</MaxTileCol>
</TileMatrixLimits>
<TileMatrixLimits>
<TileMatrix>EPSG:4326:6</TileMatrix>
<MinTileRow>15</MinTileRow>
<MaxTileRow>15</MaxTileRow>
<MinTileCol>68</MinTileCol>
<MaxTileCol>68</MaxTileCol>
</TileMatrixLimits>
```

The Tile Request:

http://xxxxxx/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?layer=seedpro%3ASP%20-%20OSM%20Brasil&style=&tilematrixset=EPSG%3A4326&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&Format=image%2Fpng&TileMatrix=EPSG%3A4326%3A2&TileCol=2&TileRow=3

The WMTS Error:

```html
<ExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://geowebcache.org/schema/ows/1.1.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
<Exception exceptionCode="TileOutOfRange" locator="TILEROW">
<ExceptionText>Row 3 is out of range, min: 1 max:2</ExceptionText>
</Exception>
</ExceptionReport>
```

So GetCapabilities says that Zoom 2 has tiles between 0 and 4
But when I query for ROW 3, it says it have min: 1 max:2.

Comment: You say you're using TileCache but in your question title you mention GWC (GeoWebCache). TileCache (Python) doesn't ship with GeoServer, and doesn't support WMTS standard.

Comment: I have misspoken.
What I wanted to say is that the GeoServer "Tile Layers" menu itself is generating a example that gives me some "Bad Request" on some tiles.